# Win10 workstation can't see shares via system names

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, windows-10

Only new Win10x64 workstations joined to the domain experience this problem. Existing and new Win7x64 systems are unaffected. Essentially they can all browse to network locations using IP address but not system name. I have tested the workstations on statics and manually set our internal DNS but the problem persists. I have also verified that we have an internal record where server1(DNS server) is pointed at itself, 192.168.168.20, with a reverse record.

We are currently using a work around where we modify the local computer's host file to include a server1 192.168.168.20 entry. This does clear up the problem but we also don't consider it a permanent solution considering it happens on every new machine.

Does anyone know what would be causing our Win10 workstations to be denied communication with our internal DNS?

*Additional Environment Information* :

- Domain Functional Level is 2008
- Windows Firewall is off
- KES has been disabled during testing

Comment: Have you tested straight name resolution via nslookup? Have you tried accessing using the FQDN?

Comment: nslookup results return "non-existent domain" when using just the server name. Using the FQDN does work and show the correct ip address within nslookup.

Comment: What is KES?...

Comment: @joeqwerty KES = Kaspersky Endpoint Security

Comment: Your share hosted on windows server or on samba?

Comment: Standard Windows file share

Comment: The DNS suffix is not being set for some reason... it should be setting this to your domain name (e.g. contoso.com) so if you queried mail it would actually ask for mail.contoso.com. This can be set in the advanced settings of IPv4 settings in Network Connections but it should be happening automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to resolve by using FQDN but not by the NetBIOS name, you would appear to have a name resolution problem. More specifically, NetBIOS name resolution is not working.

You can configure the client to append the appropriate DNS suffixes, or mess around with the NetBIOS over TCP settings either directly on the system or by setting the options over DHCP